# Building google maps inside a ruby on rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby

This is a basic map that was built:

[image: basic map]

To render it, you would put this in the .html.slim files

```
.acme-map-container-4 data=map_identifier(resource: @warehouse.id)
```

What actually happens is, the `map_identifer()` (a rails helper) inserts some data attributes,
and the javascript code uses that to initialize the google map.

A basic google map can be done with [about 11 lines of code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple). This code has many more lines,
because it lets us do the following things:

- add labels to markers
- these labels can be made clickable (user is redirected)
- the icon for the pin is overridable
- the architecture is conducive to polling via ajax - so for example on a office display, you can track your delivery driver if he's recording his latLng to a postgres backend
- maps in modals/tabs are "late initialized" for faster page loads
- the ruby code can override the default map type, for example hybrid, satellite, roadmap
- a series of latLngs can be rendered as a route
- multiple routes and multiple markers can co-exist in a single map
- a page can have multiple maps
- infoWindows or tooltips can be made to appear onClick
- interactive filtering of what pins are shown
- polygons can be drawn on a map, and persist when copied to the simple_form
- in editable mode above, custom controls are overlayed so cor example the 'clear map' button clears the drawings from the map
- when a user needs to specify a latLng in a form field, they can point it out in the map by clicking on it

This is how the javascript is structured:

```
├── acme
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── map.js
│   ├── marker.js
│   ├── polygon.js
│   └── polyline.js
```

I'm pasting `marker.js` here because the others (polyline.js, polygon.js) are pretty much in the same league when it comes to coding style.

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/acme/marker.js

// namespace
var Acme = Acme || {};

// Marker
Acme.Marker = function(geoJson) {
  // Functions
  // attach marker to google map
  this.setMap = function(m) {
    this.marker.setMap(m)
    this.infoWindow && this.geoJson.properties.infoWindowInitialState && this.geoJson.properties.infoWindowInitialState == "opened" && this.infoWindow.setMap(m)
  }

  // extend given bounds to include self
  this.extendBoundsToFit = function(bounds) {
    if (geoJson.geometry.coordinates[1]<-90 && geoJson.geometry.coordinates[1]>90) { return bounds } //exit if invalid
    if (geoJson.geometry.coordinates[0]<-180 && geoJson.geometry.coordinates[0]>180) { return bounds } //exit if invalid

    bounds.extend(
      new google.maps.LatLng(
        geoJson.geometry.coordinates[1],
        geoJson.geometry.coordinates[0]
      )
    )
    return bounds
  }

  // create associated infoWindow
  this.createInfoWindow = function() {
    if (this.geoJson.properties.infoWindowContent == undefined) { return }
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: this.geoJson.properties.infoWindowContent
    })
    infoWindow.setPosition({lat: geoJson.geometry.coordinates[1], lng: geoJson.geometry.coordinates[0]})
    return infoWindow
  }

  // possibly open infoWindow or redirect to a path on click.
  this.clickHandler = function() {
    console.log("click")
    if (this.parent.infoWindow && this.parent.geoJson.properties.clickBehavior && this.parent.geoJson.properties.clickBehavior == "openInfoWindow") {
      this.parent.infoWindow.open(this.getMap())
    }
    if (this.parent.geoJson.properties.clickBehavior && this.parent.geoJson.properties.clickBehavior == "openLink") {
      Turbolinks.visit(this.parent.geoJson.properties.clickDestination)
    }
    return
  }
  // /Functions

  this.geoJson = geoJson
  this.labelVisible = $.trim(this.geoJson.properties.label).length ? true : false
  opts = {
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.9},
    labelInBackground: true,
    icon: geoJson.properties.markerIcon, // can be a hash specifing an offset
    labelClass: 'acme-map-marker-label',
    labelVisible: this.labelVisible,
    labelContent: geoJson.properties.label,
    title: geoJson.properties.tooltip,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(geoJson.geometry.coordinates[1],
                                     geoJson.geometry.coordinates[0]),
  }
  this.marker = new MarkerWithLabel(opts)
  this.marker.set('parent', this)
  this.infoWindow = this.createInfoWindow()
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', this.clickHandler)
}
```

The main frontend code is in map.js, so it is that who would call upon marker.js to create markers for example. here it is:

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/acme/map.js
// namespace
var Acme = Acme || {};

// Map
Acme.Map = function(elem) {
  // Functions
  // create empty map and send ajax request to fetch objects
  this.init = function() {
    return this.makeMap() // a bare map
               .getMapData()
  }

  // creates empty map
  this.makeMap = function() {
    this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(this.elem, {
      center: this.defaultCenter(),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: "satellite"
    });
    this.googleMap.set('parent', this)
    return this
  }

  // downloads latitudes, longitudes for pins, polygons etc
  this.getMapData = function(options) {
    console.log("getMapData")
    if (! this.mapIdentifier()) { return this } // return early there's not enough info
    $.ajax({ url: '/api/maps/map.json', context: this, data: this.mapIdentifier(),
             success: function(ajaxData) { this.processMapData(ajaxData) }
    })
    return this
  }

  // executes after fetching map data from api
  this.processMapData = function(ajaxData) {
    console.log("processMapData")
    if (Object.keys(ajaxData).length != 2 || ajaxData.settings == undefined) { return } //invalid resp.
    this.ajaxData = ajaxData
    this.setSize().
      setType()
      .draw()
      .postZoom()
      .filtrationHooks()
      .editability()
      .finalize()
  }

  // allow ruby backend to influence the eventual width/height of map
  this.setSize = function() {
    $(this.elem).css('width',  this.ajaxData.settings.width)
    $(this.elem).css('height', this.ajaxData.settings.height)
    return this
  }

  // returns something like  {"map_secondary_resource":1128,"map_controller":"warehouses","map_resource":1335,"map_action":"edit"}
  this.mapIdentifier = function() {
    if (! $(this.elem).data('controller')) { return } // return if weird
    var data = {}
    $.each( $(this.elem).data(), function (name, value) {
      (!name.startsWith("default")) && (data[('map_'+name)] = value)  //not need to send defaults
    });
    return data
  }

  // set map type
  this.setType = function() {
    this.googleMap.setMapTypeId( this.ajaxData.settings.mapTypeId )
    return this
  }

  // focus camera when objects are present in map
  this.postZoom = function() {
    console.log("postZoom")
    if (this.mapObjects.length == 0) { return this } // nothing to do

    this.tempLimitZoom()  // alternative solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4709017
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    this.mapObjects.forEach(function(item, index) {
      bounds = item.extendBoundsToFit(bounds)
    })
    this.googleMap.fitBounds(bounds)

    setTimeout( function() {
      this.tempUnLimitZoom()
      this.singularZoom()
    }.bind(this), 500)
    return this
  }

  // gt - greater than
  this.tempLimitZoom = function() {
    if (this.ajaxData.settings.preventOverzoom) {
      this.googleMap.setOptions({maxZoom: this.ajaxData.settings.preventOverzoomGt})
    }
    return this
  }

  // undoing tempLimitZoom
  this.tempUnLimitZoom = function() {
    if (this.ajaxData.settings.preventOverzoom) {
      this.googleMap.setOptions({maxZoom: undefined})
    }
    return this
  }

  // interactive filtering
  this.filterByMarkerLabelContent = function(ev) {
    var input = $(ev.target)
    var phrase = $(input).val()
    this.mapObjects.forEach(function(item, index) {
      if (! (item instanceof Acme.Marker)) { return } // filtering by marker properties only atm
      if (item.marker && item.marker.labelContent && item.marker.labelContent.indexOf(phrase)>-1) {
        item.marker.setVisible(true)
      } else {
        item.marker.setVisible(false)
      }
    })
  }

  // listen for key presses
  // assumes only 1 filter (.map-marker-filter) exists in dom
  this.filtrationHooks = function() {
    $(elem).closest('.row').on('keyup','.map-marker-filter', this.filterByMarkerLabelContent.bind(this) )
    return this
  }

  // editability related code
  // make map editable - if asked
  this.editability = function() {
    if (! this.ajaxData.settings.isEditableMap) { return this }
    console.log("editability")
    this.createToolbar()
    this.markerEditability()
    this.polygonEditability()
    return this
  }

  this.createToolbar = function() {
    var toolbar = document.createElement('div');
    this.createCloseButton(toolbar, this.googleMap)
    this.createClearButton(toolbar, this.googleMap)
    toolbar.index = 1;
    this.googleMap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(toolbar);
    return this
  }

  this.polygonEditability = function() {
    //polygon creation event handler
    var drawingManager = this.createDrawingManager()
    drawingManager.setMap(this.googleMap);
    $.each(this.allPolygons(), function(index, item) { // marks polygons as editable
      item.polygon.setEditable(true)
    })
    //polygon creation event handler
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
      console.log("polygoncomplete "  + polygon)
      this.getMap().parent.addDrawnPolygon(polygon)
    })
    // to fully clear a map, overlays need to be removed as well
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(arg) {
      this.getMap().parent.overlays.push(arg.overlay)
    })

  }

  this.markerEditability = function() {
    // allow moving marker (1) on click
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.googleMap, 'click', function(event) {
      this.parent.moveMarker1(event.latLng)
    })
  }

  // custom control - CLEAR MAP button
  this.createClearButton = function(toolbar, googleMap) {
    var that  = this
    var clearButton = this.makeButton(
      'CLEAR MAP',
      'CLEAR ALL POLYGONS IN THIS MAP',
      toolbar)
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(clearButton, 'click', function (something) {
      $(document).trigger("acme:map:clear_polygons_clicked")
      this.clearPolygons()
    }.bind(this));
  }

  // custom control - close button
  this.createCloseButton = function(toolbar, googleMap) {
    var closeButton = this.makeButton(
      'CLOSE WINDOW',
      'Closes this pop up only. Changes are saved when you save the parent form.',
      toolbar)
    // handle CLOSE button click in dialog
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(closeButton, 'click', function (_) {
      $(document).trigger("acme:map:close_clicked", googleMap)
    });
  }

  // nice toolbar at geojson.io btw
  this.makeButton = function(label, tooltip, toolbar) {
    var buttonDiv = this.makeButtonDiv(tooltip)
    toolbar.appendChild(buttonDiv)
    var buttonLabel = this.makeButtonLabel(label)
    buttonDiv.appendChild(buttonLabel)
    return buttonDiv
  }

  this.makeButtonDiv = function(tooltip) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    div.style.borderColor = '#ccc';
    div.style.marginTop = '4px';
    div.style.marginLeft = '36px';
    div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    div.style.textAlign = 'center';
    div.title = tooltip;
    return div
  }

  this.makeButtonLabel = function(label) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto, Arial, sans-serif';
    div.style.fontSize = '9px';
    div.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    div.style.paddingRight = '4px';
    div.style.paddingTop = '7px';
    div.style.paddingBottom = '7px';
    div.innerHTML = label;
    return div
  }

  this.moveMarker1 = function(latLng) {
    console.log("moveMarker1")
    this.createMarkerIfNotExist(latLng)
    //console.log("moveMarker1 " + latLng.toJSON() )
    this.firstMarker().marker.setPosition( latLng )
  }

  this.firstMarker = function() {
    return this.allMarkers()[0]
  }

  this.markerGeoJsonTemplate = function() {
    return {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": []
      },
      "properties": {}
    }
  }

  // creates a (plain) marker in map if one doesn't exist
  this.createMarkerIfNotExist = function(latLng) {
    if (this.allMarkers().length > 0) { return }
    var markerGeoJson = this.markerGeoJsonTemplate()
    markerGeoJson.geometry.coordinates[0] = latLng.lng()
    markerGeoJson.geometry.coordinates[1] = latLng.lat()
    marker = new Acme.Marker(markerGeoJson)
    marker.setMap(this.googleMap)
    this.mapObjects.push( marker )
    return marker
  }

  this.createDrawingManager = function() {
    var dm = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLGON,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [ 'polygon'] // ['marker', 'circle', 'polygon', 'polyline', 'rectangle']
      },
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: 'red',
        strokeColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        strokeWeight: 6,
        clickable: false,
        editable: true,
        zIndex: 1
      }
    });
    return dm;
  }

  // add a polygon that the user has drawn
  this.addDrawnPolygon = function(polygon) {
    var polygon = new Acme.Polygon( this.toPolygonFeature(polygon) )
    polygon.setMap(this.googleMap)
    this.mapObjects.push(polygon)
    return this
  }

  // clearing map involves,
  // 1 setMap(null) for mapObjects
  // 2 making sure mapObjects is purged
  // 3 remove overlays
  this.clearPolygons = function() {
    console.log("clearPolygons")
    for (var i = 0; i<this.mapObjects.length; i++) {
      if (this.mapObjects[i].polygon) { this.mapObjects[i].polygon.setMap(null) }
      //if (this.mapObjects[i].marker) { this.mapObjects[i].marker.setMap(null) }
    }
    $.each(this.overlays, function(i,ov) { ov.setMap(null) })  //stackoverflow.com/a/7882263
    this.filterInPlace(this.mapObjects, function(value) { return (!(value instanceof Acme.Polygon)) })
  }
  // /editability related code

  // helps avoid the need for capybara to poll/sleep
  this.finalize = function() {
    $(elem).addClass('acme-map-inited')   // to precent double initialization
    return this
  }

  // draws pins etc on map
  this.draw = function() {
    console.log("draw")
    this.makeObjects().assignObjects()  // assign aka setMap()
    return this
  }

  // makes MarkerWithLabel/google.maps.Polygon/google.maps.Polyline etc objects
  this.makeObjects = function() {
    var that = this
    $.each(this.ajaxData.data.features, function(index, item) {
      item.geometry.type == "Point" && that.mapObjects.push( new Acme.Marker(item) )
      item.geometry.type == "LineString" && that.mapObjects.push( new Acme.PolyLine(item) )
      item.geometry.type == "Polygon" && that.mapObjects.push( new Acme.Polygon(item) )
    })
    this.savedState = this.currentState()
    return this
  }

  // objects are "assigned" to a google map using setMap()
  this.assignObjects = function() {
    var that = this
    $.each(this.mapObjects, function() {
      this.setMap(that.googleMap)
    })
  }

  this.totalMarkers = function() {
    var markers = $.grep( this.mapObjects, function( n, i ) {
      return n instanceof Acme.Marker
    });
    return markers.length
  }

  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/37319954
  this.filterInPlace = function(a, condition) {
    let i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < a.length) {
      const val = a[i];
      if (condition(val, i, a)) a[j++] = val;
      i++;
    }
    a.length = j;
    return a;
  }

  this.allMarkers = function() {
    return $.grep( this.mapObjects, function( n, i ) {
      return n instanceof Acme.Marker
    });
  }

  this.allMarkerCoords = function() {
    return $.map(this.allMarkers(), function(m, i) {
      return m.marker.position.toString()
    }).join()
  }

  this.allPolygonCoords = function() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.exportGeoJson(this.allPolygons()))
  }


  this.allPolygons = function() {
    return $.grep( this.mapObjects, function( n, i ) {
      return n instanceof Acme.Polygon
    });
  }

  // singularZoom only comes in to effect if the ajax response asked for it
  this.singularZoomApplicable = function() {
    return (this.totalMarkers() == 1 && this.mapObjects.length == 1 && this.ajaxData.settings.singularZoom >= 0)
  }

  // singularZoom - a zoom for maps with 1 item in it
  this.singularZoom = function() {
    if (! this.singularZoomApplicable()) { return }
    console.log("singularZoom")
    this.googleMap.setZoom(this.ajaxData.settings.singularZoom)
  }

  // for centering, when 0 objects in map
  this.defaultCenter = function() {
    var defaultCenter = {lat: 40.7128, lng: -74.006}  // somewhere in the state
    if ( $(this.elem).data('defaultlat') && $(this.elem).data('defaultlng') ) {
      defaultCenter.lat = $(this.elem).data('defaultlat')
      defaultCenter.lng = $(this.elem).data('defaultlng')
    }
    return defaultCenter
  }

  // accepts a google.maps.Polygon object, returns GeoJson
  // adaptation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/32752340
  this.exportGeoJson = function(polygons) {
    var geoJson = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": []
    };
    for (var j = 0; j < polygons.length; j++) {
      var polygonFeature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": []
        },
        "properties": {}
      };
      var polygon = polygons[j].polygon
      for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        var pt = polygon.getPath().getAt(i);
        polygonFeature.geometry.coordinates.push([
          pt.lng(), pt.lat()
        ]);
      }
      polygonFeature.geometry.coordinates = [ polygonFeature.geometry.coordinates ]
      geoJson.features.push(polygonFeature);
    }
    return geoJson
  }

  this.toPolygonFeature = function(polygon) {
    var polygonFeature = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": []
      },
      "properties": {}
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
        var pt = polygon.getPath().getAt(i);
        polygonFeature.geometry.coordinates.push([
        pt.lng(), pt.lat()]);
    }
    //polygonFeature.geometry.coordinates = [ polygonFeature.geometry.coordinates ]
    return polygonFeature
  }


  // the geoJson for all polygons in map
  this.allPolygonsGeoJson = function() {
    return this.exportGeoJson(this.allPolygons())
  }

  // coordinates of all markers aka pins in map
  this.markersCoords = function() {
    if (this.allMarkers().length == 0) { return [] }
    return $.map( this.allMarkers(), function(m, i) {
      return m.marker.getPosition().toJSON()
    })
  }

  // like a checksum
  this.currentState = function() {
    return (this.allMarkerCoords() + this.allPolygonCoords())
  }

  // returns true when polygons added, point moved, after original ajax load
  this.isDirty = function() {
    if (this.currentState() != this.savedState) {
      return true
    }
  }
  // /Functions


  // Main
  this.elem = elem
  this.ajaxData = {} // raw hash provided by backend
  this.mapObjects = [] // array of google.maps.Polyline/MarkerWithLabel/etc objects
  this.overlays = [] 
  this.googleMap; // new google.maps.Map(... object
}
```

On the ruby side (backend), we have these files under app/models:

```
├── map
│   ├── gig_edit_map.rb
│   ├── gig_map.rb
│   ├── tickets_map.rb
│   ├── courier_map.rb
│   ├── warehouses_map.rb
│   ├── drivers_map.rb
│   └── geo_json.rb
├── map.rb
```

I made map.rb is to be like a root namespace, much like how a gem developer would structure his `lib` directory.

```ruby
# app/models/map.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Maps - shown in various pages of the web-app.
#
module Map
  DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '400px',
    map_type_id: 'satellite',
    prevent_overzoom: true,
    prevent_overzoom_gt: 16,
    singular_zoom: nil,
    poll: -1 # tbd
  }.freeze
end
```

Mixins are a powerful concept in ruby, and favored [by many](https://golangbot.com/inheritance/) over inheritance.
`geo_json.rb` is a mixin that's `include` ed in most of the `.rb` files.
To show you how I did a mixins, here's geo_json.rb:

```ruby
# app/models/map/geo_json.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

module Map
  # GeoJSON is a format for encoding a variety of geographic data structures.
  #
  # {
  #   "type": "Feature",
  #   "geometry": {
  #     "type": "Point",
  #     "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  #   },
  #   "properties": {
  #     "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  #   }
  # }
  # GeoJSON supports the following geometry types: Point, LineString,
  # Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, and MultiPolygon. Geometric
  # objects with additional properties are Feature objects. Sets of
  # features are contained by FeatureCollection objects.
  #
  # The GeoJSON Specification (RFC 7946) In 2015, the Internet Engineering
  # Task Force (IETF), in conjunction with the original specification
  # authors, formed a GeoJSON WG to standardize GeoJSON. RFC 7946 was
  # published in August 2016 and is the new standard specification of the
  # GeoJSON format, replacing the 2008 GeoJSON specification.
  #
  module GeoJson
    def geo_json_feature_collection(arr)
      raise unless arr.is_a?(Enumerable)
      {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        "features": arr.select(&:valid?).map(&:as_geo_json)
      }
    end
  end
end
```

For every web page you would render a map, you would build a corresponding ruby class. 
Here's the code for `warehouses.rb`:

```ruby
# app/models/map/warehouses_map.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Map
  # The map shown at /warehouses
  class WarehousesMap
    include GeoJson

    def initialize(warehouse_id)
      @warehouse = Warehouse.find(warehouse_id)
    end

    def as_json
      { data: data,
        settings: settings }
    end

    def settings
      DEFAULT_SETTINGS.dup.merge({ map_type_id: 'hybrid' })
    end

    def data
      geo_json_feature_collection([point_1, point_2, line_string])
    end

    # aka source
    def point_1
      Point.new(
        @warehouse.latitude,
        @warehouse.longitude,
        label: "Source - #{@warehouse.name}",
        markerIcon: '/images/custom.png'
      )
    end

    # aka destination
    def point_2
      Point.new(
        @warehouse.address.latitude,
        @warehouse.address.longitude,
        label: "Destination - #{@warehouse.address&.addressable&.city_name}"
      )
    end

    # aka route
    def line_string
      LineString.new(
        points_of_line_string,
        snap_to_roads: true
      )
    end

    def coords_of_line_string
      @warehouse.positions.order(:location_at).pluck(:latitude, :longitude)
    end

    def points_of_line_string
      coords_of_line_string.map do |lat_lng|
        Point.new(lat_lng[0], lat_lng[1])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `maps_controller.rb` plays a central role - it's the last mile for the backend code, and serves map settings for incoming Ajax requests originating from map.js:

```ruby
# app/controllers/api/maps_controller.rb
module Api
  class MapsController < ApplicationController

    # a json response containing map metadata + pins/polygons for the map
    # GET /api/maps/map.json
    def map
      case params
      when warehouses_show_page?
        resp = ::Map::WarehouseMap.new(params["map_resource"]).as_json
      when admin_warehouses_show_page?
        resp = ::Map::WarehouseMap.new(params["map_resource"]).as_json
      when redacted_show_page?
        resp = ::Map::RedactedMap.new(params["map_resource"]).as_json
      when gigs_locations_show_page?
        resp = ::Map::GigLocationsMap.new(params["map_resource"]).as_json
      when gigs_map_page?
        resp = ::Map::GigsMap.new(current_user).as_json
      when drivers_index_page?
        resp = ::Map::DriversMap.new(current_user, params["map_driver_status_id"]).as_json
      when drivers_show_page?
        resp = ::Map::DriverMap.new(current_user, params["map_resource"]).as_json
      when drivers_edit_page?
        resp = ::Map::DriverEditMap.new(current_user, params["map_resource"], params["map_secondary_resource"]).as_json
      else
        resp = {}
      end
      resp[:settings].transform_keys!{|k|k.to_s.camelize(:lower)}
      render json: resp
    end

    private

    def warehouses_show_page?
      ->(params) { params["map_controller"] == "warehouses" }
    end

    def admin_warehouses_show_page?
      ->(params) { params["map_controller"] == "admin/warehouses" }
    end

    def redacted_show_page?
      ->(params) { params["map_controller"] == "driver/tickets" }
    end

    def gigs_locations_show_page?
      ->(params) { params["map_controller"] == "gigs/locations" }
    end

    def gigs_map_page?
      ->(params) { params["map_controller"] == "gigs" }
    end

    def drivers_index_page?
      ->(params) { params["map_controller"] == "drivers" && params["map_action"] == "index" }
    end

    def drivers_show_page?
      ->(params) { params["map_controller"] == "drivers" && params["map_action"] == "show" }
    end

    def drivers_edit_page?
      ->(params) { params["map_controller"] == "drivers" && ['edit','update'].include?(params["map_action"]) }
    end
  end
end
```

This is demo of a map that has 'drawability' turned ON:

[image: drawable]